# How to clear the cache for a symbol, i.e. Unset pattern-free DownValues 4

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider this code:

```
ClearCache[f_] := DownValues[f] = DeleteCases[DownValues[f], 
                                              _?(FreeQ[First[#], Pattern] &)]
```

**Question:** can somebody expand on the meaning of `_?` before the `(FreeQ...` segment? My research and understanding of the `_head` pattern syntax in Mathematica have defeated me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_` matches anything and the `?` checks that whatever `_` matched evaluates to `True` when passed to the function that follows: `FreeQ[First[#], Pattern] &`.

In general, `p?test` is a pattern object that stands for any expression which matches `p`, and on which the application of `test` gives `True`, as you can see in the relevant documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html).